# Pass dynamic variables with PHP ajax to Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I want to pass a variable like : childage_error1 childage_error2 childage_error3 etc.
And I have this code right here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gyermekek; i++) {
      document.getElementById('gyermekkor_error' + (i + 1) + '').innerHTML = response.window['gyermekkor_error'+i+1]
    }
```

If I put manually "gyermekkor_error1" it works but it wont work in a loop.
It works in getElementById but not in the end.

Comment: Try with `var i = 1` then you can just use `i` lower down, instead of `i + 1`

Comment: `console.log('gyermekkor_error'+i+1)` should be able to quickly show you where your mistake lies. And the solution is contained in your code already as well. (Why are you doing the _same_ thing in two different ways to begin with?)

Comment: What is the error? Are you looping one too many times?

Comment: 'gyermekkor_error01' How i make the 0 disappear?

Comment: I already told you the solution - see the very first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.window['gyermekkor_error'+i+1]`

You are adding a string to a number plus a number. Basic order of operations left to right. The code does not assume you meant to add i to 1 first.

So you are getting

```
'gyermekkor_error01'
'gyermekkor_error11'
'gyermekkor_error21'
'gyermekkor_error31'
```

You need to surround the addition part with parenthesis

`response.window['gyermekkor_error' + (i+1)]`

Or just start your loop off at one so you do not need the addition step.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= gyermekek; i++) {
  var key = 'gyermekkor_error' + i;
  document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = response.window[key];
}
```

Comment: (index):410 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gyermekkor_error1')
at ajax_request.onreadystatechange
but if i try like this: response.gyermekkor_error1 It gives me the AJAX response.There is no difference or is there?

Comment: `response.window.gyermekkor_error1` does not equal `response.gyermekkor_error1`. You are saying your object is like `{ "window": { "gyermekkor_error1": "foo" } }`. You read some answer about global variables and bracket notation and thought you needed `window`? Just use `response[key]`